# How to document Parameter of type 'function' in sphinx?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have a docstring of this form:

```
'''
Attributes
----------
_forward_fn  :  function
                Blabla...
'''
```

But sphinx does not accept the type and complains about

```
:py:class reference target not found: function
```

Despite the fact that this is what Python prints when querying the `type()` of a user-defined function. I have tried `callable`, `Function`, `Callable` as well, to no avail. It seems that the Python documentation doesn't have this type in its inventory, so I guess I'm out of luck and 
the only solution is adding the type to `nitpick_ignore` in `conf.py`?

Comment: Not sure how to reproduce this. Can you provide a complete example? Is the docstring part of a class?

Comment: Yes, but the problem will occur in other places as well, wherever `:class:` is used.

Comment: I don't know what "other places" means. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you've ever documented something with a type, that's a problem location right there. An mwe will make this simpler, but this is really a knowledge question, not a debugging one.